# Как проверить входит ли адрес в зону доставки?

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api, геокодирование

Я пишу систему для доставки Еды. У Каждой точки Производства Ограниченная зона доставки. И мне нужно каким-то образом проверять входит ли адрес в зону доставки или нет. Для геокодирования использую Яндекс Геокодер. Спасибо

Comment: Зачем Столько Больших Букв?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример Яндекса "[Проверка адреса на попадание в зону доставки](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones)" — ваш ответ. При том, что геокодер допускается использовать бесплатно только при показе карты Яндекс, это самый простой и удобный вариант.

Без отображения карты сторонние модули и библиотеки разве что.